# Is $1+1+(k+1)2^{k+1}<1+(k+2)2^{k+1}$, for $n=k+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> The question is on induction. $$2^{n+1}<1+(n+1).2^{n}$$.

I proved it but need a verification at the last step of the proof.

For $n=k$ $$2^{k+1}<1+(k+1).2^{k}$$
For $n=k+1$   $$2^{k+1}.2^2<(1+(k+1).2^{k})2^2\\ 2^{k+2}<(2+(2k+2).2^{k})\\ < 1+1+(k+1)2^{k+1}\\ <1+(k+2).2^{k+1}$$.

Any suggestion for the last step please. I am not satisfied with the last two steps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes.  It’s easy to see this by noting $1 < 2^{k+1}$ for any $k\ge 0$.  The last line is exactly the same as $1 + 2^{k+1} + (k+1)2^{k+1}$.  But you also don’t need induction for this, it’s really quite elementary by the same methods you used to establish the induction.

Comment: do you want to prove that $$2+(k+1)2^{k+1}<1+(k+2)2^{k+1}$$?

Comment: i think it is better to send us the original problem

Comment: The original problem is on induction topic. it says to prove that $2^{n+1}<1+(n+1).2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the base case, we test with $n = 1$, and note that 
$$
4 = 2^2 <  1 + (1 + 1)2^1 = 1 + 4 = 5.
$$
Now, assume it holds until $n = k$.  That is, assume that we have that 
$$
2^{k + 1} < 1 + (k + 1)2^{k}.
$$
Now, for the $n = k + 1$ case, try multiplying by 2 on both sides instead of $2^2$.  We get 
\begin{align*}
2^{k + 1} \cdot 2 &< (1 + (k + 1)2^{k}) \cdot 2 \\
2^{k + 2} &< 2 + (k + 1)2^{k + 1}. \\
\end{align*}
Now we can use the inequality that
\begin{align*}
2 + (k + 1)2^{k + 1} &= 1 + 1 + 2^{k + 1} k + 2^{k + 1} \\
&< 1 + 2^{k + 1} + 2^{k + 1} + 2^{k + 1}k \\
&= 1 + 2(2^{k + 1}) + k(2^{k + 1}) \\
&= 1 + (k + 2)2^{k + 1}.
\end{align*}
Combining all these inequalities gives that 
$$
2^{k + 2} < 2 + (k + 2)2^{k + 1},
$$
as desired.  Thus, by the induction hypothesis, the result holds for all $n$.